# Tasker: Voice response to phone calls

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, tasker

I was wondering whether it would be possible to use Tasker to answer a phone call and then say something to the caller (either through TTS or sound file) and then hang up? Would something like that be possible? I was thinking about making a task which will tell people to call me later because I'm busy now etc.

If it is could you outline how to make it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure whether the [AutoVoice](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AutoVoice/com.joaomgcd.autovoice) addon could be used for this. Though it would use your speaker, the "other end" should be able to hear: Incoming call → Pickup, AutoVoice (blabla...), Hangup. Just a raw idea.

Comment: FYI There is no way, that I've heard of, for any app to output audio into a call itself.

Comment: I doubt you can programatically, certainly not without root. The dialer is heavily protected and apps are denied any access to it. As @Bort said, you just can't. Also, it may be easier for someone to just use their voicemail than a dedicated app?

Comment: @Bort that's device dependent. There are a lot of "answering machines" on Google Play which reportedly work for some people/devices (while not working on others). And still: if the speakers are loud enough, they might be heard "on the other side".